# Find the determinant of a matrix with entries $\frac1{a_i+b_j}$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Find the determinant

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
  \dfrac1{a_1+b_1} & \dfrac1{a_1+b_2} & \ldots & \dfrac1{a_1+b_n} \\
  \dfrac1{a_2+b_1} & \dfrac1{a_2+b_2} & \ldots & \dfrac1{a_2+b_n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  \dfrac1{a_n+b_1} & \dfrac1{a_n+b_2} & \ldots & \dfrac1{a_n+b_n}
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I know you have to multiply -1 to the first row and add it to every rest rows, but I'm unsure of what to do after.

Comment: look up the cauchy/hilbert matrix